# Join two columns into one in a SpatialDataFrame, but omitting NAs In R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, na, spatial-data-frame

I'm trying to join two columns of a SpatialDataFrame (shapefile) into one using the R program, but in both columns there are empty spaces, when they are together with the name plus NA, however I would like the NAs not to appear in my new column. I used the paste function.
something like this:

```
  This is the structure of my SpatialDataFrame:


  ID           city                city2
1  1      saõ paulo                 <NA>
2  2      Rio de Janeiro            <NA>
3  3           <NA>            Belo Horizonte
4  4           <NA>            Curitiba
```

obs. my original data is not this and has more columns

I used this:

```
data$newCity <- paste(data$city, data$city2) # I don't want to show in my data Na
```

1.

```
ID          city          city2                newCity
  1      saõ paulo         <NA>            saõ paulo NA
  2  Rio de Janeiro        <NA>            Rio de Janeiro NA
  3        <NA>       Belo Horizonte       NA Belo Horizonte
  4        <NA>       Curitiba             NA Curitiba
```

In fact this would be the desired result:

```
ID          city          city2                 newCity
 1      saõ paulo         <NA>                saõ paulo
 2    Rio de Janeiro      <NA>               Rio de Janeiro
 3        <NA>         Belo Horizonte         Belo Horizonte
 4        <NA>          Curitiba              Curitiba
```

Comment: Please always provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `coalesce` from `dplyr` package:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,
                 city = c("sao paulo", "rio de janeiro", NA, NA),
                 city2 = c(NA, NA, "Belo Horizonte", "Curitiba"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(City = coalesce(city, city2))
  ID           city          city2           City
1  1      sao paulo           <NA>      sao paulo
2  2 rio de janeiro           <NA> rio de janeiro
3  3           <NA> Belo Horizonte Belo Horizonte
4  4           <NA>       Curitiba       Curitiba
```

Comment: returned the following error: Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : _no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')"_, I think it's because my real data is a spatialDataframe

Comment: I presume it is indeed related to your `SpatialPolygonsDataframe`. Can you edit your question to provide the output of `head(NameofYourSpatialDataframe)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Another `base R` option could be:

```
with(df, pmax(city, city2, na.rm = TRUE))

[1] "sao paulo"      "rio de janeiro" "Belo Horizonte" "Curitiba"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `paste` glues the character columns together, separated by a space, i.e. "_". Try this:

```
data$newCity <- ifelse(is.na(data$city), data$city2, data$city)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried with this code but it didn't work, see what returned me:               
   ID           city          city2                    newCity
1  1      saõ paulo           <NA>                  2
2  2 Rio de Janeiro         <NA>                 1
3  4           <NA>        Belo Horizonte        1
4  5           <NA>            Curitiba                2

Comment: Looks like the character columns are actually factors. You can check this with `str(data)`, which shows you the type of your variables. In case of factors this worked for me: `df$newCity <- ifelse(is.na(as.character(df$city)), as.character(df$city2), as.character(df$city))`. Preferable solution would be to convert factors to character columns after loading the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unite()` in `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unite(newCity, city:city2, remove = F, na.rm = T)
```

The argument `na.rm = T` works only on character columns.